# visual composer not showing on my website

Tags: wordpress

Yesterday I worded on visual composer and it was working great. But today no visual composer element is showing. I have checked by deactivating / deleting all the 3rd party plugins but still no improvement.

**http://www.hycubetech.co.uk/**  I tried anything I could try.. but nothing I could get..
Need some wonder

Comment: Please check console, you should find some **Javascript** errors.

Comment: I removed all the error but still not working

Comment: I even reinstalled the wordpress and tried taht thing again but still no result

Comment: We can't help you without proper explanation of your question, Nothing is clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

Its done.. I fixed thing.. I copied all the **short codes** and save those on separate file. Then in reinstalled the wordpress and put those **short codes** on the same page. Every thing worked fine.
Thanks for your co-operation **Milap**.